# How does the Epic Dodge feat work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, attack, dodge

Question mostly related to a difficulty in translating.

The Epic Dodge feat (cadv. 191) says "when struck by an attack from an opponent you have designated...you automatically avoid all damage from the attack"

Does this apply to a "full attack action" (which would mean that you can ignore all the attacks received by one enemy in a round)?

Answer (score 4):

### This works only on one attack per round

The full text of the feat is

> **Once per round**, when struck by an attack from an opponent you have designated as the object of your dodge, you may automatically avoid all damage from the attack.

If you are hit by multiple attacks due to someone using a full attack action and striking you repeatedly with attacks, you can still only use it only **once per round**, when struck by an attack, not multiple times on multiple attacks.

Comment: Thank you, I read it as "using (activating) it once per round to protect me from a full attack". And I thought it was just too strong.